# OpenGL shader problem

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl

So, I've been working on this game engine for a while now, and just the other day my friend tried running the program and his output doesn't match my output...

My Program Output: 
[image: poorly textured donut]

His Program Output:
[image: poorly rendered donut]

both are supposed to be donuts, but his donut is very much misformed. I made sure that all the vertices and indices were loaded on his machine correctly so it has to be something going wrong in the shaders

Vertex Shader:

```
#version 150
in vec3 in_Position;
in vec3 in_Normal;
in vec2 in_TexCoord;

out vec2 ex_TexCoord;
out vec3 Normal;

uniform mat4 model_matrix;
uniform mat4 view_matrix;
uniform mat4 projection_matrix;

void main(void){
    ex_TexCoord = in_TexCoord;
    Normal = vec3(transpose(inverse(model_matrix * view_matrix)) * vec4(in_Normal, 1.0));
    gl_Position = projection_matrix * view_matrix * model_matrix * vec4(in_Position,1.0);
}
```

Fragment Shader:

```
#version 150

in vec2 ex_TexCoord;
in vec3 Normal;

out vec4 frag_color;

uniform vec3 lambient;
uniform vec3 ldifuse;
uniform vec3 lspecular;

uniform vec3 light_pos;
uniform vec3 position;
uniform vec3 lstrength;
uniform sampler2D color_texture;

float dcont;
vec3 light_dir;
float intensity;
vec3 normal;
vec3 light;

void main(void){
    float dist = length(position-light_pos);
    float att = (1/(1.0+(0.01*dist)+(0.001*dist*dist)));
    light_dir=normalize(light_pos-position);
    normal = normalize(Normal);
    intensity = dot(light_dir,normal);
    light = normalize(light_pos-position);
    dcont = max(0.0,dot(normal,light));
    vec3 ambient = lambient;
    vec3 difuse = dcont * ldifuse;
    vec3 specular = lspecular;

    if(intensity > 0.95){
        frag_color= vec4((difuse + ambient) * vec3(texture2D(color_texture,ex_TexCoord))*(att),1.0);
    }
    else if(intensity > 0.5){
        frag_color = vec4((difuse + ambient) * vec3(texture2D(color_texture,ex_TexCoord))*0.9*(att),1.0);
    }
    else if(intensity > 0.25){
        frag_color = vec4((difuse + ambient) * vec3(texture2D(color_texture,ex_TexCoord))*0.7*(att),1.0);
    }
    else{
        frag_color = vec4((difuse + ambient) * vec3(texture2D(color_texture,ex_TexCoord))*0.4*(att),1.0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is your system the *only* computer this works on? It may help to know the differences in hardware. Also, based on what you've said, it appears that the loading is not the issue. If you've matched up the vertices being loaded as exactly the same then it's the display that's the issue, so you may want to rephrase your title.

Comment: yeah, it seems like it could be a harware dependent problem

Comment: Your shaders might be buggy.  Different drivers will do different things with non-conforming shader code.

Comment: shall I post my code for the shaders?

Comment: @BrendanWebster Yes, please post the shader code as well.

Comment: yeah, it's the shaders, what's the difference between conforming and non conforming shader code

Comment: didn't post the shaders because the website wasn't displaying them in the code tag well enough

Comment: Could it be lack of support for GL_UNSIGNED_INT index data? Although you don't have so many vertices that it would be a problem. Just an idea.

Comment: @BrendanWebster: conforming shaders are those that are legal and follow all the rules of the target version of GLSL.  Non-conforming ones use invalid featuers or syntax that an overly permissive compiler (like NVIDIA's) will happily accept.  I can't know if it's your shaders; just post them and someone will be able to help more.  Nobody will judge you because the code tag doesn't make them pretty.

Comment: @DaleyPaley the unsigned suggestion didn't work.
Added the code, but it's rather hard to read

Comment: Sorry, my fault, I wasn't clear at all. All I meant is to try changing GL_UNSIGNED_INT to GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT and change your index array to [GLushort]. I know that OpenGLES cant use unsigned ints for indexing. I dont know about your friends computer though. But it sounds like its a shader problem anyway. It was just an idea because I have been bitten by that in the past.

Comment: @DaleyPaley, nope that didn't help

Comment: the "out" keyword is what's causing the problem, I think it's because it's using the Normal for the gl_Position

Comment: actually that's not the exact problem, it just seems to be a problem with the Normal in general and using "out" on it

Comment: sorry for all the comments but, the Normal equation in vertex shader is what is messing it up

Comment: yes, it should look like this: Normal = (mvit*vec4(in_Normal,0.0)).xyz;
Where mvit is the inverse transpose of the concatenated view*model matrix passed in to the shader. Also, normals should have 0 as 4th component because they are directions not positions.

Comment: @BrendanWebster: You should post that in an answer (perfectly fine to answer yourself, if you've found the solution), so others will be able to find this in case they encounter something similar.

Comment: I will make sure to post the solution to the problem as soon as I'm 100% sure of it

Comment: Aw man, I almost pointed that Normal problem out for you, too, right after you posted the shader code but didn't think that was the specific problem and was going to leave it for you to figure out another day.   Sorry for making you waste time figuring that out on your own... hopefully it was at least a good learning exercise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alright, so as stated in the comments the problem is the equation for the Normal. Nvidia accepts poor shader programming, so if you have Nvidia just make sure you check with the standards of the shader version. Also don't use keywords such as "Normal" or other words that would cause a name collision.